# $L^p$ Boundedness of Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

How does one show that the operator $(-\Delta_D)^{-1}\Delta$ is bounded from $L^4(\Omega)$ to itself, where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is a bounded smooth domain, and $-\Delta_D$ is the Dirichlet Laplacian with homogeneous boundary.